# Linker error with armadillo with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, linker-errors, armadillo

I'm running an example from the Armadillo tutorials

```
# include <iostream>
# include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
  {
  mat A = randu<mat>(4,5);
  mat B = randu<mat>(4,5);

  cout << A*B.t() << endl;

  return 0;
  }
```

I've written a brief CMakeLists.txt based on this

```
project(DebugTest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

find_package( ARMADILLO REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${ARMADILLO_INCLUDE_DIR} )

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  ${GCC_ARMADILLO_LINK_FLAG}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_ARMADILLO_LINK_FLAG}")

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries( main ${ARMADILLO_LIBRARIES} )
```

When I run `cmake CMakeLists.txt` followed by `make` from the command line, I get a linker error.

Output of `cmake CMakeLists.txt`

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.1.0.8020038
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.1.0.8020038
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Armadillo: /usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.dylib (found version "7.800.2") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Me/Workspace/DebugTest
```

Output of `make`

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::enable_if<__is_forward_iterator<char*>::value, void>::type std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init<char*>(char*, char*) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      arma::arma_ostream_state::arma_ostream_state(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in main.cpp.o
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in main.cpp.o
      arma::arma_ostream_state::arma_ostream_state(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o
  "std::logic_error::logic_error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      void arma::arma_stop_logic_error<char const*>(char const* const&) in main.cpp.o
      void arma::arma_stop_logic_error<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.cpp.o

(... Many many lines skipped ...)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm certain that my CMakeLists.txt is correct because I can build the project in QtCreator, just not on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use QtCreator to build the project, everything runs as expected. cmake outputs

```
Running "/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.1/bin/cmake /Users/Me/Workspace/DebugTest '-GCodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/clang++ -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=" in /Users/Me/Workspace/build-DebugTest-Desktop-Default.
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.1.0.8020038
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.1.0.8020038
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/Me/Workspace/DebugTest
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE
```

The compiler outputs

```
17:52:43: Running steps for project DebugTest...
17:52:43: Starting: "/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.1/bin/cmake" --build . --target all
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable main
[100%] Built target main
17:52:45: The process "/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.1/bin/cmake" exited normally.
17:52:45: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

And the main method runs beautifully

### Why does it work in this context?

There are a couple extra flags used by QtCreator in its cmake call

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.1/bin/cmake /Users/Me/Workspace/DebugTest '-GCodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/clang++ -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:STRING=
```

I tried a couple of variations and it appears the `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/clang++` flag is required to link successfully.

The commands

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=/usr/bin/clang++
make
```

Successfully compile the project on the command line.